# Why do these two equations represent the same line if and only if $a-a'$ and $b'$ are real multiples of $b$?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-geometry

The Chap. 1, Sec. 2.3 in *Complex Analysis* by Lars V. Ahlfors writes

> A straight line in the complex plane can be given by a parametric equation $z= a + b t$, where $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers and $b \neq 0$; the parameter $t$ runs through all real values. Two equations $z = a + b t$ and $z = a' + b' t$ represent the same line if and only if $a' - a$ and $b'$ are real multiples of $b$.

I find it difficult to understand it. How to conclude that these two equations represent the same line if and only if $a-a'$ and $b'$ are real multiples of $b$? My idea is that there exists a "bijection" between $z = a + b t$ and $z = a' + b' t$; that is, we can find a $t_0\in\mathbb{R}$, which satisfies that $$a+b(t-t_0)=a'+b't.$$ And then? Or are there any other ways to explain this statement?

Comment: Call the equations $z_1=a+bt_1, z_2=a'+b't_2$. Setting $t_1=0$ we obtain the existence of a real $r$ such that $a=a'+b'r$, i.e.: $a-a'=b'r$ is a real multiple of $b'$. On the other side, letting $t_1=1$, you obtain the existence of $r'\in\mathbb R$ such that $a+b=a'+b'r'\iff b=b'(r'-r)$, so $b$ is a real multiple of $b'$ too. Can you work out the other direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking of complex numbers as plane vectors the real line
$$
a+bt\qquad a, b\in\mathbb{C}, t\in\mathbb{R}
$$
is the line through $a$ and parallel to $b$.
Thus if the lines
$$
a+bt,\qquad a^\prime+b^\prime t
$$
coincide the two "direction" vectors $b$ and $b^\prime$ must be parallel, i.e. one a real multiple of the other.

So, after reparametrization, the second line can be written
$$
a^\prime+bu,\qquad u\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
Again. the two line coincide, thus we must have a coincidence
of sets of numbers
$$
a+bt=a^\prime+bu
$$
as $t$ and $u$ vary in $\mathbb{R}$. But this means that for some $t$ and $u$ (and we can be assume $t\neq u$ or else the result becomes trivial) we have an equality of numbers
$$
a-a^\prime = b(u-t)
$$
which is exactly what we want.